# how to add child routes to bjyauthorize guard?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

my **module.config.php** file is

```
....... other route and setting .....

     'doctors' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/doctors',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'doctors',
                    ),                    
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array( 
                    'filter' => array(
                        'type'    => 'segment',
                        'options' => array(
                                'route'    => '/:type/:search',
                                'defaults' => array(
                                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                                    'action'     => 'doctors',
                                ),
                                'constraints' => array(
                                   // 'search' => '[a-z0-9]+', 
                                    'type' => '[a-z0-9]+', 
                                ), 
                                'defaults'    => array(),
                            ), 
                    ) , 
                )

            ), 

....... other route and setting .....
```

and my **bjyauthorize** config for this route is

```
 array('route' => 'doctors', 'roles' => array('admin' , 'doctor' , 'staff' , 'user', 'dps', 'vender' , 'ops' , 'crm' , 'analytic','editer'  , 'guest' ) ),
```

now my problem is

I am able access

```
http://BASEURL/doctors
```

but I can't able access (unauthorise )

```
http://BASEURL/doctors/city/Car-Nicobar
```

can any one help me to do this. ?

please let me know you want to know more setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem these days. You need to specify the child_routes name after your parent route like this.

## Old code:

`array('route' => 'doctors', 'roles' => array('admin' , 'doctor' , 'staff' , 'user', 'dps', 'vender' , 'ops' , 'crm' , 'analytic','editer'  , 'guest' ) ),`

## New code:

`array('route' => 'doctors/filter', 'roles' => array('admin' , 'doctor' , 'staff' , 'user', 'dps', 'vender' , 'ops' , 'crm' , 'analytic','editer'  , 'guest' ) ),`